# does non retina devices download @2x images when installing from the AppStore?

Tags: ios

I'm concerned with the size of my ios application. My question is :
when a non-retina device is **downloading** an application from the AppStore, does it download retina images as well (i.e. the @2x ones), although it will never be used ?
Said differently, does the AppStore expose different application pacakges, according to the  targeted device ?

thanks !

Comment: Your app is packaged as a zip file (with ipa extension). Users simply get the one and only ipa file for your app. Nothing is downloaded separately. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all binaries downloaded from the App Store are exactly the same (except for the iTunes receipt that gets injected).

I'm guessing your `@2x`-files are large and you're looking for a way to compress your binary, so here are some solutions:

- If you want to download the `@2x` or non-`@2x` resources on runtime,
  you can store them in a documents folder, close to your binary, but
  that would require an additional download for the user.
- You can draw some of your artwork on runtime, using CoreGraphics. CoreGraphics is quite extensive and if you're experienced enough, you can do (almost) exactly the same you do with Photoshop. (I've been able to port several UI elements to code, including those with an inner shadow, inner glow, drop shadow, gradient, etc.).
- You can convert your resources to WebP (which compresses pretty well, without dropping quality) or use a PNG compressor (since the PNG compressor Xcode uses does not compress that well).
- Try to make your resources into patterns. For example, if you're using a background that repeats itself every 100x100, than it would make sense not saving it as a 640x960 file but instead as a pattern, and to again use CoreGraphics to render it on runtime. Don't save navigation-bars as 640x88 (320x44) but instead as either 640x2 (320x1) or if you want to use rounded corners or something, use `[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]`.

I'ld personally recommend going for a combination of the second and fourth option, since it does not affect the user's experience and it does not involve using a non-standard image format.

Answer (score 0):

It will download everything: normal image and @2x images